# Rails: undefined method error when move codes from view to helper file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In approval.html.erb

```
<% @approval.each do |approval| %>
    <td><%= Material.find_by_id(approval.material_id).m_name%></td>
<% end %>
```

I want to move `Material.find_by_id(approval.material_id)` to approval helper file.

In approval_helper.rb

```
def approval_material
  Material.find_by_id(approval.material_id)
end
```

Then, I modify approval.html.erb

```
<% @approval.each do |approval| %>
    <td><%= approval_material.m_name%></td>
<% end %>
```

However, it shows me an error

> undefined local variable or method `approval'

What causes the error , how to fix it ? Thanks

Comment: `def approval_material(approval)` and `<%= approval_material(approval).m_name %>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass a parameter to the helper method`approval_material` method. Something like:

```
def approval_material(approval)
  Material.find_by_id(approval.material_id)
end
```

And then on your view you can call it like:

```
<% @approval.each do |approval| %>
    <td><%= approval_material(approval).m_name%></td>
<% end %>
```